# Which font family do we use for new applications in 2013?

Tags: font

I am working on the new design for a product. It is a serious product with file management and related display options. Previously **Lucida, Arial, Helvetica and Verdana** fonts were used but currently most applications use different font families. So, I would like to use newer fonts like:

- Proxima Nova
- Helvetica Neue
- Open Sans
- Roboto

My concerns are that

1. Most of the above fonts look different in different sizes. I want a font that will look okay in both category (**Readability Issue**).
2. The typical font should gel well in other languages as well (i18n)

I need information on how this will fit in our newer applications.

Comment: This question is not constructive - it's of an open-ended polling variety.

Answer (score 2):

That would depend on your platform, I think. Some platforms allow the user to set fonts, and if so, you should generally follow those preferences.

Answer (score 1):

I think the font Open Sans will be better option and can be used. Actually speaking the older fonts are preferred by many people as they look proper in all the resolutions as well as on different devices.

If possible you can continue using those fonts. For Microsoft applications generally **Segoe UI / Calibri** is mainly used. For Mac applications **Lucida MAC** font can be used so that the display will be proper.

Hope this will help.